# sending xcode application to a friend

Tags: xcode

Hey, although i am not done with my application and have alot of learning to do, i want to know is it possable to send it via email to a friend?

i have tried to send something very simple to just show my friend what i'm doing.

in gmail i composed a message and attached a file, "my project" but it said something about could not send because firewall or something.. so i made sure it was http: and not https, still no luck.. do i have to activate or publish my project to send it? and if so how?

i thought after you clicked build and run in xcode, that was the finished project, save to desktop.. it opens when i click it from desktop just cant send it.. please help.

thanks in advanced!!!

Answer (score 0):

It may be too big to send. Did you zip it? Just share it via [Dropbox](http://db.tt/k2cDZAI).

Comment: how do i zip it? and the file im trying to send is the debug, because thats the only one when i click it opens my built project without xcode and the interface poping up, is this correct or no?

Comment: Take a look at Ad Hoc Distribution for Apps. http://developer.apple.com/programs/ios/distribute.html Googling may give you some instructions too. (Zipping is just a matter of selecting what you want to zip, and then File > Compress... " ")